# Redirect legacy php links with Querystring - in IIS / ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a new site in ASP.NET (4) on IIS 8.

I need to redirect legacy php links from the previous site - which have a querystring - to new pages (which now have a friendly URL). The PHP page is the same for many of the redirects, only the querystring changes (eg id=6).

eg
site.com/page.php?id=6  >  site.com/an-article
site.com/page.php?id=7  >  site.com/another-article

What is the easiest / quickest way of doing this?

Comment: You will want to use [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX). Pass page.php to a handler that looks at the query string and redirects it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to build the new .net link and send an HTTP 301 to the user with that link:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: ' . $url);
die();
```

The "url" variable is the new translated url for your site.

Comment: Thanks - how do I implement this? Where does that code go? Bear in mind I have 100 links to manage

Comment: This goes at the top of your php page that is handling your requests.

Comment: ahh - I don't have PHP. I have ASP.NET on IIS. I need to forward the old links to the new ASP site.

Answer (score 0):

Manage your old & new links in database. Store the OldLink, NewLink in database. And for load all the list in cache in App_start to be accessed for all subsequent requests.

You will need to have URL rewriting for this.

You will need to work in global.asax

in application_beginrequest method write your url rewriting logic

e.g.

```
string aspxurl = string.Empty;
string querystring = string.Empty;
string[] strTmpQuery = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Split('?');
if(strTmpQuery[0].Endswith(".php"))
{
  aspxurl = strTmpQuery[0].Substring(0,strTmpQuery[0].Length-4) + ".aspx";
}

if(strTmpQuery.Length>1 && strTmpQuery[1].Trim() != "")
{
querystring = strTmpQuery[1];
}
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(aspxurl, "", querystring);
```

NOTE : You will have to tweak web.config so that IIS sends requests for PHP files to .net engine. look for HttpModule/HttpHandler for url rewriting

Comment: I would rather just have some kind of text file - way lighter weight than a DB (there is no db on the site currently).